# Users model also need to be buyers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Noob here.  I have a rails app that has users and postings.  I need to add buyers, which are users.

Users can post things, but can also view others posts and then select to buy those posts.

I am not sure how to setup this in my posts or users model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup something like this,

You can add a field to posts, `buyer_id`

In Model Posts

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :buyer, :class => "User", :foreign_key => "buyer_id"
```

In Model User

```
has_many :posts
has_many :purchases, :class => "Post", :foreign_key => "buyer_id"
```

This is one way of doing things.

Comment: So doing it this way can I get paths like post/buyer?  Or do I need to do this with :through?